# Issue in calling the CallableStatement.execute();

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

When I try to call the execute `CallableStatement.execute()`,
I get the following exception

> java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer
>   ('student'@'127.0.0.1:3306') does not exist

```
myDB URL- :jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo?useSSL=false
Username- student
password- student
```

If I try to establish a connection and execute a simple select statement using a statement object the same code works fine.

And I also checked the Stored Procedure snippet which has the same definer `CREATE DEFINER=`student`@`127.0.0.1:3306``

I have attached my snippet and a couple of image links ensure the correctness of definer,.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and how to fix this

Code:
[SQL EXCEPTION THROWN][1]
[image: Connection Credentials]
[image: Stored Procedure Snippet]

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Storedprocedures {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection mycon = null;
        CallableStatement calstat = null;
        PreparedStatement stat = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String dep = "HR";
        int salary = 10000;

        try {
// Get a connection to database


mycon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo?useSSL=false", "student", "student");
System.out.println("Conn success");

// Prepare the stored procedure call
calstat = mycon.prepareCall("{call increase_salaries_for_department(?, ?)}");

// Set the parameters           
calstat.setString(1, dep);
calstat.setDouble(2, salary);

// Call stored procedure
calstat.execute();

// Prepare statement            
stat = mycon.prepareStatement("select * from employees where department=?");

            stat.setString(1, dep);

// Execute SQL query
            rs = stat.executeQuery();
//Helper Method 
            RsetIterator.rset(rs);

        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the mysql documentation it specify that CREATE DEFINER

> should be a MySQL account specified as 'user_name'@'host_name',

[Create Stored Procedure Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

One possible solution is to change CREATE DEFINER TO

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'student'@'127.0.0.1'
```

or

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'student'@'localhost'
```

or

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'student'@'%'
```

Just try removing the port number from definer.